# Is there a way to pass the result of a function to matplotlib's subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I do know how to plot multiple subplots in `matplotlib`, I just want to know if there is a shortcut to use the function below to plot multiple plots.

```py
def plot_2d_vectors(
    vec: np.ndarray,
    labels: List[str],
    colors: List[str],
    save: bool = False,
    title: str = "",
    *args,
    **kwargs,
) -> None:
    """Plot 2D vectors.

    Args:
        vec (np.ndarray): The vectors to plot.
        labels (List[str]): The labels of the vectors.
        colors (List[str]): The colors of the vectors.
        save (bool, optional): If True, save the plot. Defaults to False.

    Example:
        >>> vec = np.array([[0, 0, 3, 5], [0, 0, 8, 6], [5, 11, 3, 5]])
        >>> labels = ["v1", "v2", "v3"]
        >>> colors = ["r", "b", "g"]
        >>> plot_2d_vectors(vec=vec, colors=colors)
    """

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
    if not isinstance(vec, np.ndarray):
        vec = np.asarray(vec)
        assert vec.shape[0] == 2, "The vector must be 2D."

    for i, (v, l, c) in enumerate(zip(vec, labels, colors)):
        x_pos, y_pos, x_dir, y_dir = v
        ax.quiver(
            x_pos,
            y_pos,
            x_dir,
            y_dir,
            angles="xy",
            scale_units="xy",
            color=c,
            scale=1,
            alpha=0.6,
        )
        # Here we use f-strings to annotate.
        # Note if vectors do not start at origin (i.e. x_pos !=0 or y_pos !=0),
        # then the text annotation needs to be added to x_pos and y_pos.
        if x_pos > 0 or y_pos > 0:
            ax.text(
                x_pos + x_dir, y_pos + y_dir, f"{l}: $({x_dir}, {y_dir})$", fontsize=16
            )
        else:
            ax.text(x_dir, y_dir, f"{l}: $({x_dir}, {y_dir})$", fontsize=16)

    # Here we take the min and max of all the vectors so we can set a reasonable x and y limit.
    x_min, x_max = min(vec[:, 0] + vec[:, 2]), max(vec[:, 0] + vec[:, 2])
    y_min, y_max = min(vec[:, 1] + vec[:, 3]), max(vec[:, 1] + vec[:, 3])
    ax.set_xlim([0, x_max + 5])
    ax.set_ylim([0, y_max + 5])
    ax.set_xlabel("x-axis", fontsize=16)
    ax.set_ylabel("y-axis", fontsize=16)
    ax.set_title(title, size=18)
    ax.grid(True)
    if save:
        fig.savefig("vector.svg", format="svg", dpi=600)

    return ax
```

I tried:

```py
vec1 = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 2], [0,0,2,1]])
vec2 = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 2], [0,0,2,1]])

labels = ["v1", "v2", "v3"]
colors = ["r", "b", "g"]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(18, 9))  # width 18 height 9

axes[0] = plot_2d_vectors(vec=vec1, labels=labels, colors=colors, save=True)
axes[1] = plot_2d_vectors(vec=vec2, labels=labels, colors=colors, save=True)
plt.show()
```

But the plot does not show side by side. Is there a way to do it without changing too much the function itself? I would have thought `axes` is a list of 2 `matplotlib` objects, and by assigning them to the function call, it will show the two plots.

Comment: You call `plt.subplots` at the global level, then again inside `plot_2d_vectors`.  I'm sure that's not what you want.

Comment: @TimRoberts You are right, what is a good way to remove the local `fig` and `ax` in the function? If I remove them, then `ax` won't be defined inside the function.

Comment: Then you pass it to the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function slightly to accept an axis keyword argument and then pass the axis on which you want to plot to the function.

```
def plot_2d_vectors(
    vec: np.ndarray,
    labels: List[str],
    colors: List[str],
    save: bool = False,
    title: str = "",
    ax=None,
    *args,
    **kwargs,
) -> None:
```

Then you can just pass `axes[0]` or `axes[1]` for `ax` keyword argument to plot on the given axis.

```
vec1 = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 2], [0,0,2,1]])
vec2 = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 2], [0,0,2,1]])

labels = ["v1", "v2", "v3"]
colors = ["r", "b", "g"]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(18, 9))  # width 18 height 9

plot_2d_vectors(vec=vec1, labels=labels, colors=colors, save=True, ax=axes[0])
plot_2d_vectors(vec=vec2, labels=labels, colors=colors, save=True, ax=axes[1])
plt.show()
```